# Sentence structure (subject and object)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Do these sentences mean the same thing:

1. I have nothing to do with the accident
2. The accident has nothing to do with me

Answer (score 1):

Well, both are similar and the same in this context.

> "*It* has nothing to do with me."
>
> "*I* have nothing to do with that."

The two are interchangeable due to pragmatics and idiomacy.